# Can't get bigger resolution then 1152x864 when running Ubuntu 12.10 or 13.04 in Hyper-V

Tags: resolution, virtualization

I'm running a fresh installed ubuntu under Hyper-V on Windows 8. I can't select a resolution bigger then 1152x864.

xrandr in the ubuntu VM states the maximum is 1152x864 (my local monitors are running at 1920x1050 and above so I would like a higher res.

Is there any way to run at a higher res?

Answer (score 3):

The maximum possible resolution for Ubuntu (Linux) running in Hyper-V is **1920x1080**

Here is how you can change the resolution of **Ubuntu (Linux)** running in Hyper-V:

- Open the Terminal and type: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
- Find the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, and add
  `video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080` (or your preferred resolution) in between
  the quotes like this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"`
- Save and Exit
- Run `sudo update-grub`
- Restart Hyper-V (restarting Ubuntu (Linux) might be enough)

This is for Ubuntu 14.04, but I think it will work for 12.10 and 13.04 too. Here is my original [**post**](https://superuser.com/a/782046/172416).

Answer (score 2):

If it helps anyone else I wasn't able to get [Devid's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/509038/527764) to work for me because I had the 'RemoteFX 3D Video Adapter' on my Virtual Machine after reading some other article.

Once I removed it, I got the full resolution (1920x1080) that I was looking for after following Devid's steps.

**Settings->Hardware->3d Video Adapter**

Click on 'Remove'